# Хочу оптимизировать код для spinner

Tags: java, android, xml, android-spinner

не так давно стал учиться программировать приложения. хочу нескольким спиннерам дать один и тот же код для выполнения. Вопрос в следующем: можно-ли оптимизировать код.

Есть список, который нужно показывать при нажатии. есть код спиннера, и код работы.

```
    public void sp_all(String mass[], View name_sp){

        ArrayAdapter<String> my_c = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mass);//выбор спинеру
        my_c.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Spinner sp_my_card = (Spinner) name_sp;
        sp_my_card.setAdapter(my_c);//доставка значения
    }

    public void than(){
        sp_all(my_card, findViewById(R.id.sp_my_card_the_c));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl1_the_c));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl2_the_c));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl3_the_c));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl4_the_c));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl5_the_c));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl6_the_c));
        sp_all(my_card, findViewById(R.id.sp_my_card_the_d));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl1_the_d));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl2_the_d));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl3_the_d));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl4_the_d));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl5_the_d));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl6_the_d));
        sp_all(my_card, findViewById(R.id.sp_my_card_the_r));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl1_the_r));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl2_the_r));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl3_the_r));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl4_the_r));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl5_the_r));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl6_the_r));
        sp_all(my_card, findViewById(R.id.sp_my_card_the_ro));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl1_the_ro));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl2_the_ro));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl3_the_ro));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl4_the_ro));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl5_the_ro));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl6_the_ro));
        sp_all(my_card, findViewById(R.id.sp_my_card_the_w));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl1_the_w));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl2_the_w));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl3_the_w));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl4_the_w));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl5_the_w));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl6_the_w));
        sp_all(my_card, findViewById(R.id.sp_my_card_the_l));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl1_the_l));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl2_the_l));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl3_the_l));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl4_the_l));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl5_the_l));
        sp_all(player, findViewById(R.id.sp_pl6_the_l));
    }
```

xml код спиннера:

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/sp_my_card_the_c"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/choise_menu"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingTop="2dp"
android:paddingBottom="2dp"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:textSize="20sp" />
```

пробовал команду:

```
android:onClick
```

Но, если правильно понял работает только с кнопкой..

Comment: что-то не очень понятно что вы пытаетесь сделать, уточните вопрос пожалуйста.

Comment: У вас только 2 массива, поэтому я бы циклом прошёлся по всем іd спинеров (сначала для одного массива, потом для другого), хранил бы список спинеров (а лучше 2), чтобы не вызывать каждый раз тяжелый findViewById. Потом если юзер нажал на спинер из первого списка, то первая логика, если на второй - вторая.

Comment: @MarkCain
А можно пример, как циклом пройтись?
Да, я изначально хотел их на 2 типа разделить или на 2 функции, чтобы один шел по 1му массиву, а второй по другому, но как сделать чтобы без findViewById не понимаю(

Comment: Или каким образом можно записать id всех спиннеров в список?

Comment: Просто попробовал создать список таким образом, ничего не получилось:

`public Spinner[] pl = {findViewById(R.id.sp_pl1_the_c),findViewById(R.id.sp_pl2_the_c)};`

Answer (score 0):

Приблизительно так:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        than(); //видимо...
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // blah-blah если ничего не выбрано
    }

});
```

Comment: На данный момент, программа делает то же самое, я просто посмотрел, что у меня много одинаковых функций, и хотел узнать можно ли создать одну функцию, чтобы она одновременно проверяла id спиннера, который выбран и выполнялась.